# Saving output of \ commands to disk

Tags: psql

When I try to run the following command:

```
my_db> \copy \dt *. to /home/john/list.txt
```

I get an error:

```
\copy: parse error at "*"
```

Why? How can I save the output to disk?

Comment: Use `\o`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\o` command as documented in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

specifically:

```
> \o <path_to_the_file_where_you_want_the_output>
> [your command]
> \o
```

the last statement switches the output of `psql` back to `stdout`.